# Mongodb-compass load doesn't work in mogosh?

Tags: mongo-shell, mongodb-compass

Running the `load` command in the MongoDB Compass `mongosh` shell (on macOS Version 1.28.1) doesn't work:

```
\>load("test.js")
MongoshUnimplementedError: [COMMON-90002] load is not currently implemented for this platform
```

but running `help` displays `load` as one of the available commands.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's macOS version 1.28.1?

Comment: 11.4 macos, 1.28.1 is for mongodb compass

Answer (score 0):

Compass currently does not support loading files. You can either copy-paste the script or you can run it with mongosh in the terminal.